# Subset Sum Variation - subset has X number of items

Tags: javascript, algorithm, subset-sum

I'm looking for an algorithm that will allow me to **quickly access** (not necessarily print) every X item subset of a 300 item set that, when the values of the items in the subset are added up, equals Y. Repetition is allowed and order is important. All values of the 300 item set are positive.

So for example,

300 item set: [1.5, 1.34, 3, .25, 2.333, 1.75, .125, .675, 2, 4, .75, ....]

X = 5

Y = 6

Algorithm generates:

[2, 2, 1.5, .25, .25]
[2, 2, .25, 1.5, .25]
[2, 1.5, 2, .25, .25]
[1.5, 2, 2, .25, .25]
[2, 1.75, .5, .5, 1.25]
[2, 1.75, .5, 1.25, .5]
[2, 1.75, 1.25, .5, .5]
[2, 1.25, .5, .5, 1.75]
[1.25, 2, .5, .5, 1.75]
[.5, 2, .5, 1.25, 1.75]
[3, 1, 1, .5, .5]
[1, 3, 1, .5, .5]
[1, 1, 3, .5, .5]
[1, 1, .5, 3, .5]
[1, 1, .5, .5, 3]

And so on....

[2, 2, 1.5, .25, .25] is allowed and

[2, 1.75, .5, .5, 1.25] is not the same thing as [1.25, .5, .5, 1.75, 2].

I realize that this is a variation of the Subset Sum problem but I can't seem to find any helpful examples of this variation anywhere online. Right now my current solution implements nested loops (the number of nested loops is determined by the value of X) That works fine when X is small but quickly get very slow when X starts going up. Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: @NinaScholz Here is a codepen with what I currently have: https://codepen.io/Wcomp/pen/rNBgyjq?editors=0012

Answer (score 0):

An approach is to collect subsets and check if the length of the subset and sum fits.

If necessary, you could permutate the subsets.

```js
function subsetSum(array, sum, items) {

    function iter(taken, index, subsum) {
        if (taken.length === items && subsum === sum) return result.push(taken);
        if (taken.length === items || subsum === sum || index === array.length) return;
        iter([...taken, array[index]], index, subsum + array[index]);
        iter(taken, index + 1, subsum);
    }

    var result = [];

    iter([], 0, 0);
    return result;
}

var result = subsetSum([1.5, 1.34, 3, .25, 2.333, 1.75, .125, .675, 2, 4, .75], 6, 5);

console.log(result.map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Wow. Super interesting. I had considered recursion but could figure out how to implement it. Thanks!